# DRY an Azure Function Application in .NET Core

Tags: .net, .net-core, azure-functions

Defining an Azure Function Application I have many Functions that are almost the same:

```
public static class FunctionA
{
    [FunctionName("function_a")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")]HttpRequest request, ILogger logger)
    {
        //... Authentication, etc

        return result = ServiceA.Do(request);
    }
}


public static class FunctionB
{
    [FunctionName("function_b")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")]HttpRequest request, ILogger logger)
    {
        //... Authentication, etc

        return result = ServiceB.Do(request);
    }
}

//...
```

**Is there a way to [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) this code?**

Ideally I would like to have something like inheritance with generics, but I can't because static classes can only inherit from object.

Comment: if you re using azure function v2, funtions don't have to be stasic.

Answer (score 1):

One idea that would come to my mind would be to use routing. You would basically define only one external HTTP triggered function and switch in there based on a routing attribute. Something like this:

```
[FunctionName("function_external")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "service/{service}")]HttpRequest request, string service, ILogger logger)
{
    //... Authentication, etc

    // Depending on how many cases you have, you probably want some smarter lookup here
    switch(service)
    {
       case "a": return ServiceA.Do(request);
       //...
    }
}
```

It's not a perfect, generic solution, but at least something you could easily implement today.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies) or [API management](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/expose-a-function-app-via-api-management-by-linking-it-to-a-new-or-existing-api-is-now-available/) for routing.